# How to do regex search using variables in Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to do regex match in Ansible (2.7) using variable initialized at the beginning of the script

Variable used for the regex match-

```
group: 12
```

Following is the line of code that is supposed to do the match

```
set_fact: run_pc="{{ lacp_output|select("match","Po{{ group }}") | list}}"
```

Input is a list written below -

> ```
> lacp_output = 
> ["Flags:  D - Down        P - Up in port-channel (members)",
>         "        I - Individual  H - Hot-standby (LACP only)",
>         "        s - Suspended   r - Module-removed",
>         "        S - Switched    R - Routed",
>         "        U - Up (port-channel)",
>         "        M - Not in use. Min-links not met",
>         "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
>         "Group Port-       Type     Protocol  Member Ports",
>         "      Channel",
>         "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
>         "10    Po10(SD)    Eth      NONE      --",
>         "11    Po11(SU)    Eth      LACP      Eth1/1(P)    Eth1/2(P)    ",
>         "12    Po12(SU)    Eth      LACP      Eth1/3(P)    Eth1/4(P)    ",
>         "100   Po100(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "121   Po121(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "122   Po122(SD)   Eth      LACP      Eth2/1(D)    ",
>         "123   Po123(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "125   Po125(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "322   Po322(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "323   Po323(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "345   Po345(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "456   Po456(SD)   Eth      NONE      --",
>         "777   Po777(SD)   Eth      NONE      --" ]
> ```

I'm trying to have a exact match for Po12 from the above list.

Actual output -

```
TASK [assert] ***************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "run_pc | length>0",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Can not find port channel 12"
}
```

Expected output

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "run_pc": [
        "12    Po12(SU)    Eth      LACP      Eth1/3(P)    Eth1/4(P)    "
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
- set_fact:
    run_pc: "{{ run_pc|default([]) + [ item ] }}"
  loop: "{{ lacp_output }}"
  when: item is search('Po' ~ group ~ '\(')
```

The fixed task with select is below

```
- set_fact:
    run_pc: "{{ lacp_output|select('search','Po' ~ group ~ '\\(')|list }}"
```